# Why do I get empty objects in my collection Many-to-Many

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1, dql

I am getting empty objects in my collection. I have a manytomany relationship and updated my schema..

I have 2 entities;

- Vacancy
- Meetup

A vacancy can have more than 1 Meetup.

My Vacancy entity;

```
/**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Meetup", inversedBy="vacancies", cascade={"persist"}, indexBy="id", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $meetups;
```

Constructor of Vacancy entity;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->meetups = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Getters and setters;

```
/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getMeetups()
{
    return $this->meetups;
}

/**
 * @param Meetup $meetup
 */
public function addMeetup(Meetup $meetup)
{
    $this->meetups->add($meetup);
}

/**
 * @param Meetup $meetup
 */
public function removeMeetup(Meetup $meetup)
{
    $this->meetups->removeElement($meetup);
}
```

My Meetup entity;

```
/**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Vacancy", inversedBy="meetups", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $vacancies;
```

In my repository I am doing such thing as;

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('group');
$qb->innerJoin('group.vacancies', 'vacancy');
$qb->innerJoin('vacancy.meetups', 'm');
```

And my result looks like;

```
"meetups": [
        {},
        {},
        {}
      ],
```

Whats wrong with this relation? I have 3 records and I get 3 empty objects.
Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:** My serialization file looks like; (this is my Vacancy serialization file)

`clubhouseMeetups:
      expose: true
      groups: [app,vacancies]`

Comment: Please give us the code that give you this output, it seem to be a serialization problem. The problem don't come from your repository because you have 3 outputs

Comment: Here is my serialization code;
`getMeetups:
      serialized_name: meetups
      groups: [vacancies]`

Comment: Can you update your question with the configuration please ^^' Unreadable without indentation

Comment: @Mcsky I've updated my question!

Comment: And the controller's action code too ^^'

Comment: @Mcsky What I return is a new Array collection with the joins I make in my question. EDIT: Thanks for your help, it was the serialization!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ Your ManyToMany relationship isn't correct. When you have a bidirectional ManyToMany you should have one `inversedBy` and one `mappedBy`on the other side (cf http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional).

```
/**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Vacancy", mappedBy="meetups", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $vacancies;
```

2/ If you try to use your `Meetup` entity in order to add `Vacancy` your same getters and setters will not work because you will need to add the objects in both directions

```
/**
 * @param Vacancy $vacancy
 */
public function addVacancy(Vacancy $vacancy)
{
    $vacancy->addMeetup($this);
    $this->vacancies->add($vacancy);
}
```

This is not required for `inversedBy` and if you do the same code you will have a infinite loop. The best solution (I think) is to only use one entry point for this relationship, use `inversedBy`on it, also add the object in the other side and never use the other side.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Unfortunately I did what you said; adding an inversedBy and mappedBy, but still getting the same output.. What could be possibly wrong? The setters are not important in this case, but I really want the output of my many-to-many relation.

Comment: My answer is only for the save. If you have saved the recordings correctly but there is just an output problem it is due to your serialization. What is your configuration ? I don't think the serializer component of Symfony can handle many to many relationship automatically because there is also an infinite loop (Vacancies have Meetups that have Vacancies ...). So you should configure your serialization and don't display vacancies for the meetup serialisation

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed the serialization!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a serialization file for my meetup, but when I added it worked! Thanks for mentioning serialization guys!

Comment: No problem, we are to self-help ;)